# PHP SimpleXML Breaking when trying to traverse nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to read the xml information that tumblr provides to create a kind of news feed off the tumblr, but I'm very stuck.

```
<?php
    $request_url = 'http://candybrie.tumblr.com/api/read?type=post&start=0&num=5&type=text';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);

    if (!$xml) 
    {
        exit('Failed to retrieve data.');
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach ($xml->posts[0] AS $post) 
        {
            $title = $post->{'regular-title'};
            $post = $post->{'regular-body'};
            $small_post = substr($post,0,320);

            echo .$title.;
            echo '<p>'.$small_post.'</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Which always breaks as soon as it tries to go through the nodes. So basically "tumblr->posts;....ect" is displayed on my html page.

I've tried saving the information as a local xml file. I've tried using different ways to create the simplexml object, like loading it as a string (probably a silly idea). I double checked that my webhosting was running PHP5. So basically, I'm stuck on why this wouldn't be working.

EDIT: Ok I tried changing from where I started (back to the original way it was, starting from tumblr was just another (actually silly) way to try to fix it. It still breaks right after the first ->, so displays "posts[0] AS $post....ect" on screen.

This is the first thing I've ever done in PHP so there might be something obvious that I should have set up beforehand or something. I don't know and couldn't find anything like that though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
<?php
$request_url = 'http://candybrie.tumblr.com/api/read?type=post&start=0&num=5&type=text';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);

if ( !$xml ){
    exit('Failed to retrieve data.');
}else{
    foreach ( $xml->posts[0] AS $post){
        $title = $post->{'regular-title'};
        $post  = $post->{'regular-body'};
        $small_post = substr($post,0,320);

        echo $title;
        echo '<p>'.$small_post.'</p>';
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$xml->posts` returns you the *posts* nodes, so if you want to iterate the *post* nodes you should try `$xml->posts->post`, which gives you the ability to iterate through the *post* nodes inside the first *posts* node.

Also as Needhi pointed out you shouldn't pass through the root node (*tumblr*), because `$xml` represents itself the root node. (So I fixed my answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
First thing in you code is that you used root element that should not be used.

    <?php
        $request_url = 'http://candybrie.tumblr.com/api/read?type=post&start=0&num=5&type=text';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);

        if (!$xml) 
        {
            exit('Failed to retrieve data.');
        }
        else 
        {

           foreach ($xml->posts->post as $post) 
            {
                $title = $post->{'regular-title'};
                $post = $post->{'regular-body'};
                $small_post = substr($post,0,320);
                echo .$title.;
                echo '<p>'.$small_post.'</p>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```